# Don't enable tool-bar mode when run in terminal?

Tags: tool-bar

I have .emacs in my `~` which turns off tool-bar-mode
The problem is that when I run Emacs from terminal, rather than standalone Mac app, it fails on that line `Symbol's function definition is void: tool-bar-mode` , and stops executing the rest of `.emacs`. Any suggestion how to get around that?

Comment: The linked answer is one way to address this; but the underlying issue is that the default Emacs available on Mac OSX’s terminal is relatively ancient (22). You would do well to use a newer version in the terminal. What I do is set up an alias in my .bashrc that uses the GUI version’s nox mode, something like:  alias emacs=“$VISUAL -nw” where VISUAL points to the shiny Emacs in /Applications

Comment: hm, I have /Applications/Emacs.app, but that doesn't work as command-line app. Also find . -name "emacs" in that dir didn't find anything called 'emacs'

Comment: It’s there but buried. Try /Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs